# How do i choose a runtime environment when using new-azwebapp?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am currently building a script to automate the creation of an azure web app.  The frontend is built in react and deploys fine.  The backend is built using node and doesnt run when its been published.  I think that by default New-AzWebApp creates a .net windows runtime environment and i want a linux node.js environment.  I need to know how to set this in an azure powershell script.

I've already tried to alter the App Settings after the app has been created.  Changing the WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION to 10.16.3 via Set-AzWebApp

```
New-AzWebApp -Name backend$webappname -Location $location -AppServicePlan $webappname -ResourceGroupName discoverTest$workItemId `
```

This will create the app but when the files are uploaded the app doesn't run.  I think i need the right runtime environment, but i don't know how to set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you have a **Linux** App Service Plan in your resource group. And see the [Supported Versions of Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro#languages) in Azure App Service on Linux, the `10.16.3` may not be supported.

[image]

Then you can try the commands as below, my sample uses a `10.14` node.js version.

```
#Create a Linux web app
New-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -Name <web-app-name> -AppServicePlan <linux-app-service-plan-name> 
#set it with node.js 10.14 
$config = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName "<web-app-name>" -ApiVersion 2018-02-01
$config.Properties.linuxFxVersion = "NODE|10.14"
$config | Set-AzResource -ApiVersion 2018-02-01 -Force
```

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Here is the sample definition command for creating new web app in Azure:

```
New-AzWebApp
   [-ResourceGroupName] <String>
   [-Name] <String>
   [-Location] <String>
   [[-AppServicePlan] <String>]
   [[-SourceWebApp] <PSSite>]
   [[-TrafficManagerProfile] <String>]
   [-EnableContainerContinuousDeployment]
   [-IgnoreSourceControl]
   [-IgnoreCustomHostNames]
   [[-AppSettingsOverrides] <Hashtable>]
   [[-AseName] <String>]
   [[-AseResourceGroupName] <String>]
   [-IncludeSourceWebAppSlots]
   [-AsJob]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [-WhatIf]
   [-Confirm]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

**`-AseName`** is the app service environment which you can use for setting the environment.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning

Hope it helps.

Comment: AppServiceEnvironment is a completely different concept and is unrelated to the runtime configuration of a web app. This answer should be deleted.