# Publish-AzWebApp throwing an aggregate exception, need to understand why/ how to debug

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am currently building a powershell script which creates 2 web app services in azure and then publishes the apps.  The first app, which is a react app, publishes.  The backend, built using node.js, throws an aggregate exception.  I dont't know what to do with this or how to debug it.

I have tried isolating the second publish command to see if anything is interfering with it, but it still throws the same error.

```
Publish-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup -Name frontend$webappname -ArchivePath "C:\Users\Charles\Desktop\Timesheet App\Discover\DiscoverBuild.zip"

Publish-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $linuxresourcegroup -Name backend$webappname -ArchivePath "C:\Users\Charles\Desktop\Timesheet App\Discover\SNAP.zip"
```

Expect the app to publish ok, instead receive the following error:

Publish-AzWebApp : One or more errors occurred.
At C:\Users\Charles\Desktop\Timesheet App\Discover\deployScript.ps1:127 char:1
+ Publish-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $linuxresourcegroup -Name backend ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Publish-AzWebApp], AggregateException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.WebApps.Cmdlets.WebApps.PublishAzureWebAppCmdlet

Comment: If you [deploy it in VS code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-nodejs#deploy-the-website), will it work? Just to confirm if the issue was caused by the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was caused by a setting being wrong when the app service was created.  When the app service is created I needed to set "clientAffinityEnabled": true.  I did this in an arm template but you can probably change the settings in antoher way.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the application log to debug.

Navigate to the `App Service logs` in your web app in the portal -> select the `Application Logging` with `File System`.

Then run your command again, after a while, navigate to `Log stream` -> check the log.

[image]

Comment: Hi Joy, thanks for the response.  Unfortunately when i try to access the log stream i get a 502 error.  Have i gotten something wrong?

Comment: @cpbattrick Did you create the web app via [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57821251/how-do-i-choose-a-runtime-environment-when-using-new-azwebapp) or directly in the portal?

Comment: i created the app using New-AzResourceGroupDeployment and an arm template in the end.

Comment: apparently Your selected runtime stack does not currently support remote debugging.  Maybe this is the issue?

Comment: @cpbattrick Not sure, my runtime stack is `node.js 10.14 `, the `Log stream` works fine.